# Textview not sticking to the right edge of the screen (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, textview, text-alignment

I'm trying to have some textview stick to the right side of the screen (and align it right). I want to do this programmatically but can't find a proper way to do so.

I tried using setGravity and setTextAlignment. But none seem to work.

```
answershort.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
answershort.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void createanswershort(String key){
        answershort = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams av = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Width of TextView
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView
        av.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, laatstetxtview.getId());
        av.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, laatstetxtviewsmall.getId());
        av.setMargins(35,10,25,0);
        answershort.setLayoutParams(av);
        int sID = Tools.generateViewId();
        answershort.setId(sID);
        answershort.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        answershort.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
        answershort.setText(Html.fromHtml(key).toString());
        answershort.setTextSize(15);
        answershort.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        answershort.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-condensed", Typeface.NORMAL));
        rl.addView(answershort);
        laatstetxtview = ts;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following rule.

```
av.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Also, you should probably remove

```
av.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, laatstetxtviewsmall.getId());
```

You are trying to align the views to the right of the screen, not to the right of each other.